# Calculate Age while entering D.O.B manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have used Ajax Calender to find the Age, I have used the calender on one textbox and shown the Age on Next Texbox. Till now everything is fine, but Now I have two problems

First Problem:- I want the Age Textbox to be Disable so that user can't change the Age, but as I make it disable it doesn't store anything in the Database, now I don't understand what to do.

Second Problem:- It might be possible that User start entering the D.O.B manually and not by selecting it from calender, in that case nothing is calculated, how to apply functionality in such a manner that still Age get's calculated.

JavaScript code is as follows, now how to make it work while the User enter the D.O.B manually in the Textbox!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DateSelectionChanged(e) {

        var today = new Date();
        var dob = e.get_selectedDate();
        var months = (today.getMonth() - dob.getMonth() + 
                      (12 * (today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear())));
        document.getElementById("txtCONSULTANT_AGE").value= Math.round(months/12);
        document.getElementById("txtCONSULTANT_AGE").readOnly = true;
    }    
</script>
```

Here DateSelectionChanged is called on the OnClientDateSelectionChanged of Ajax Calender Extender

Thanks is Advance.

Comment: Can you show  your code..that will help in understanding more. Are you using C# /java ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, it was very simple.

Create another function and in that function just fetch the value from the Textbox and pass in into variable dob, so it would be something like this:-
Earlier:-

```
dob = e.get_selectedDate();
```

Now

```
dob = (new Date(document.getElementById("txtDATE_OF_BIRTH").value));
```

Everything else will remain same. so final code would be

```
        function findage() {
          var PresentDay = new Date();
          var dob = (new Date(document.getElementById("txtDATE_OF_BIRTH").value));
          var months = (PresentDay.getMonth() - dateOfBirth.getMonth() + 
                 (12 * (PresentDay.getFullYear() - dateOfBirth.getFullYear())));
         document.getElementById("txtCONSULTANT_AGE").value=Math.round(months/12);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the age:

```
var age = Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime()-(new Date($('#myAgeTextBox').val())).getTime())/(1000*60*60*24*365));
```

where `myAgeTextBox` is the id of your textbox(assuming the user has entered the date in the proper format)

Edit: Making the code slightly more readable

```
var currentDate = (new Date()).getTime();
var dobDate = (new Date($('input').val())).getTime();
var annualMilliSeconds = 1000*60*60*24*365;
var age = Math.floor((currentDate-dobDate)/(annualMilliSeconds));
```

Comment: The val of an input sent to the date constructor? Seems unlikely that the string value would match the ISO8601 date string format don't you think?

Comment: I did say I was assuming that. The OP could probably put some sort of hover text 'date format should be MM/DD/YYYY'. Maybe even put a RegEx check before submitting

Comment: Probably better to use a date widget instead, ISO8601 is not mm/dd/yyyy see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15 it is not a good idea to ever pass a user entered value into date constructor. It would be better to use regex to parse the user entered string and manually construct the string in the right format.

Comment: ISO8601 says `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` but the date constructor can read `MM/DD/YYYY` as well. The OP is already using some sort of date widget I think

Answer (score 0):

To Disable your age box using HTML use

```
<input type="text" name="age" readonly="readonly" />
```

Or

```
<input type="text" name="age" disabled />
```

for JavaScript use

```
document.getElementById('age').readOnly = true;`
```

Or

`document.getElementById('age').disabled = true;`

Note: Disabled should only be used if you want to remove it from the submit as well